# Disallow Clang-Format From Messing With Comments

Tags: c++, clang-format

I'm having trouble getting my clang-format to quite cooperate with multi-line comments. I have tried:

```
CodePragmas: '^[^ ]'
```

But this still results in the following. Before formatting:

```
class Test
{  
/* =======
 * Public Functions
 * ======== */
public:
};
```

After formatting:

```
class Test
{  
  /* =======
 * Public Functions
 * ======== */
public:
};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have a slightly different comment format, but same situation.  If you know the format of your block comments all use the same pattern, I think something like this will work:

```
CommentPragmas:  '/\* =======\n((.+\n.+)+)======== \*/'
```

If you want to exclude all multi-line block comments, I think this will work:

```
CommentPragmas:  '/\*(.+\n.+)+\*/'
```

I found that the ColumnLimit still applies to those comments, causing them to wrap in undesirable ways.  Otherwise, clang-format (3.8) leaves those blocks untouched.