# Force clang-format to respect doxygen block comments

Tags: doxygen, clang-format

I use long block C-style Doxygen comments in my C/C++ code. This is style #4 listed on https://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html and looks like this (running out to 80 characters)...

```
/**************************************************************************//**
* \file
* \date   2017-01-02
* \author Alex Hogen
******************************************************************************/
```

If I run clang-format on this, it **inserts a single space** between the two forward slashes, so it looks all goofy like this....

```
/**************************************************************************/ /**
* \file
* \date   2017-01-02
* \author Alex Hogen
******************************************************************************/
```

- I have `SpacesBeforeTrailingComments` set to 2, so that can't be the problem.
- Tried `CommentPragmas` regex [`\/\*+\/\/\*+`](https://regexr.com/3ijaf).
- Tried `CommentPragmas` regex [`/\*(.+\n.+)+\*/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36361434/3638827)
- I've tried setting `ReflowComments` to `false`

... but none of those things have worked.

I understand there are two comments in this block, but I can't find any clang-format parameter addressing block comments on the same line. How can I stop clang-format from inserting this space?

And I don't want to solve this by [disabling clang-format](https://releases.llvm.org/3.9.0/tools/clang/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html#disabling-formatting-on-a-piece-of-code) for every Doxygen comment block. That seems ridiculous.

Any good suggestions?

Comment: The more I look at this, the more I'm thinking the solution is to switch from the above format to [format #2](https://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/docblocks.html) (replace two forward slashes at end of first line with one exclamation mark just after the first asterisk on the first line). This would look like a single block comment to clang-format but should still be Doxygen compatible.

Comment: New link for prev comment: [Qt style / format #2](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/docblocks.html)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In your `.clang-format` file:

```
CommentPragmas:  '^\\.+'
```

This will make it not format comment line that starts with a backslash followed by a word. This works even though there is an asterisk before the doxygen comment because clang-format automatically ignores asterisks and whitespace at the beginning of every comment line.

Comment: can you please comment on 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60473112/clang-format-automatically-changes-function-block-comments-how-to-disable-it