# clang-format automatically changes function block comments, how to disable it?

Tags: c, regex, clang, clang-format

When I select `ColumnLimit` any non-zero value. It converts block comments into Doxygen block comments (it adds space before `*` on a new line). But I do not want to change it. How can I disable it?

My .clang-format file

```
ColumnLimit: 100
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
UseTab: Never
```

It converts the following block comments

```
/*****************************************************************************
*   A brief comments.
*
*   @param theory .
*
******************************************************************************/
```

into this

```
/*****************************************************************************
 *   A brief comments.
 *
 *   @param theory .
 *
 ******************************************************************************/
```

NOTE: It added spaces before each line, I do not want these spaces.
And I don't want to solve this by disabling clang-format for every Doxygen comment block. That seems ridiculous.

Any good suggestions? :-)

Comment: I think `CommentPragmas` can solve it, but I am not sure how to use it. Anyone with experience of the regular expression can give it a try.

Comment: why do you use regex tag for this question?

Comment: @Predicate `CommentPragmas` take a regular expression to process the comments, that's why I tagged it with regex

Comment: The two look identical, where is the difference?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now. However, the second block is what doxygen usually looks like i think, and is definitely more natural to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following line in your `.clang-format` file

```
CommentPragmas:  '^[^ ]'
```

This will force the clang-format not to alter any comments in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off `ReflowComments` should prevent clang-format from modifying comments.

**.clang-format:**

```yaml
ReflowComments: false
```

**Example:**

```
false:
// veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of information
/* second veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of information */

true:
// veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of
// information
/* second veryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryVeryLongComment with plenty of
 * information */
```